# Option value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form with the following field:

```
<input type="text" name="text" id="text">
```

I want that JavaScript takes the value of the field, so I think I should use the following code:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function GetTextBoxValue(text)

    {

        alert(document.getElementById(text).value);

    }
//-->
</script>
```

This code has to change the value of a drop-down option.

```
<option value="value from JavaScript/text from the textbox">other</option>
```

Is that possible that text from the textbox is the value of the option? If yes, what I have to write here option value="value from JavaScript" so it would work correctly?

Comment: It's possible, but you'd have to either dynamically create the `<option>` element using Javascript and then append it to the correct `<select>` element, or dynamically update the `<option>` elements `value` property.

Comment: have you tried anything? if you google "get value from input javascript" and "change option value with javascript" you could have already had the answer

Comment: Surely this is possible. What exactly do you want to do, when should this action happen?

Comment: @Bergi I'd vote for the `blur` event fired from that textbox, though `keypress` or `keyup` may also be suitable choices.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Sure these are possibilities, but I asked the **OP**...

Comment: @Phil I already did it but as you can see I don't have the answer. I'm pretty new in coding and thus haven't had real contact with JS and don't know JS's functions etc.

Comment: @Bergi I have an uploading form and an user can choose destination folder from a drop-down menu. If the folder doesn't exist the user selects other from the menu and a textbox comes up (it's done using JS). The user enters new folder name into the box and then clicks on submit button. Data is sent and PHP makes a new folder and uploads the file there. But at the moment the new folder creation part doesn't work (if folder is selected from the drop-down everything's fine). What I need is that when user wants to make a new folder, he enters new folder's name into the box.

Comment: @Bergi JS takes the value from the box and replaces drop-down option "Other"'s value with the box values. I know it might be too complex but I haven't come up a better idea. And after clicking on submit button HTML takes "Other"'s value and sends it to PHP. I know my code is unsecure but as I'm the only one at the beginning who is using the code then I just want to get it work. Maybe you could give me some tip what I should to do. (Hopefully you got the idea because I'm not very good writing in English. If you don't get the idea, just say and I try to explain again.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I see two solutions for your problem. The first is a live value update:

```
<select id="folder" name="folder">
   <option ...
   ... </option>
   <option id="otheroption" value="New">Other</option>
</select>
<div id="otherfolder" style="display:none">
   <label for="otherinput">New folder name:</label>
   <input id="otherinput">
</div>
<script> // here, or execute the following onload/ondomready
    document.getElementById("folder").onchange = function(e) {
        // I guess you have this piece of code already
        document.getElementById("otherfolder").style.display =
            this.options[this.selectedIndex].id == "otheroption" ? "" : "none";
    };
    document.getElementById("otherinput").onkeyup = function(e) {
        document.getElementById("otheroption").value = this.value;
    };
</script>
```

The second one would be to dynamically change the `name`s of the select and input boxes (with quite the same markup), to determine which value would be sent to the server as the `folder` parameter:

```
    document.getElementById("folder").onchange = function(e) {
        var name = "folder",
            other = this.options[this.selected].id == "otheroption";
        document.getElementById("otherfolder").style.display = other ? "" : "none";
        document.getElementById("otherinput").name = other ? name : "";
        this.name = other ? "" : name;
    };
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working! But there's still a small problem. If I enter a new folder's name into the box, for example "picture", then a folder called "pictur" is created. For some reason the last letter is omitted. Do you have any idea, why?

Comment: Uh, sure. When the keypress event fires, the new letter has not yet appeared. I guess this is fixed with my last edit

Comment: Thank you! It's working very well now. I'm really-really grateful for you!

Answer (score 1):

here is a demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function setOptionValue() {
                document.getElementById("option").value = document.getElementById("text").value;
                document.getElementById("option").text = document.getElementById("text").value;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="text" />
        <select>
            <option id="option"></option>
        </select>
        <button type="button" onclick="setOptionValue()">Set a value in the text box and press me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That doesn't **do** anything, though, since `setOptionValue()` is never called.

Comment: @Tom I tried this code but it isn't working. I wrote some text into the textbox and clicked on the button but nothing happened.

Comment: yes, you won't see it happen, but the value of the option will be set; I'll edit my code so the text of the option will also be set.